# where not exists error in upsert function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have gotten a lot of help writing a strong upsert function for postgresql.  I am trying to insert values into a table with 3 columns, two are foreign keys, and one text.

I have a very similar function that works great, it just does not have the subqueries like this one does.  I am getting an error

```
"ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"
LINE 24:   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sel)"
```

the function:

```
create or replace function upsert_dish_cluster_to_network(n_id INT, c_id INT, amsover TEXT)
RETURNS SETOF dish_cluster_to_network AS 
$func$
BEGIN

LOOP
    BEGIN

    RETURN QUERY
    WITH sel AS (
        SELECT dctn.id
        FROM   dish_cluster_to_network dctn
        WHERE  dctn.network_id = (SELECT id FROM unv_network WHERE amscode = n_id)
        AND    dctn.cluster_id = (SELECT id FROM dish_cluster_network WHERE axsyscode = c_id)
        FOR    SHARE
        ),
         ins AS (
        INSERT INTO dish_cluster_to_network (network_id, cluster_id, amsname_override)
        VALUES (
            (SELECT id FROM unv_network WHERE amscode = n_id),
            (SELECT id from dish_cluster_network WHERE axsyscode = c_id),
            amsover
            )
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sel)
        RETURNING *
        ),
         upd AS (
        UPDATE dish_cluster_to_network dctn
        SET    network_id       = (SELECT id from unv_network WHERE amscode = n_id),
               cluster_id       = (SELECT id from dish_cluster_network WHERE axsyscode = c_id),
               amsname_override = amsover
        FROM   sel
        WHERE  sel.id = dctn.id
        AND    (      dctn.network_id    IS DISTINCT FROM (SELECT id FROM unv_network WHERE amscode = n_id)
            OR    dctn.cluster_id    IS DISTINCT FROM (SELECT id FROM dish_cluster_network WHERE axsyscode = c_id)
            )
        RETURNING dctn.*
        )
    SELECT * FROM ins
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM upd;

    RETURN;

    EXCEPTION WHEN UNIQUE_VIOLATION THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'Something Bad Happened';
    END;
END LOOP;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I cannot figure out why I could not have the WHERE NOT EXISTS line.  If I comment out that line the function always inserts new entries and never updates.

Comment: Have you tried "where not in (SELECT 1 FROM sel)"

Comment: Is sel available at that point?

Comment: @Alicia WHERE NOT IN (SELECT 1 FROM sel) still returns a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `where` clause for the insert command. So replace `values` with a `select`

```
ins AS (
    INSERT INTO dish_cluster_to_network (
        network_id, cluster_id, amsname_override
    )
    select
       (SELECT id FROM unv_network WHERE amscode = n_id),
       (SELECT id from dish_cluster_network WHERE axsyscode = c_id),
       amsover
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sel)
    RETURNING *
),
```

Comment: That did it.  Completely overlooked that. Thanks!